# HTML E CSS - Porque As Imagens Não Estão Aparecendo

Tags: html, css

Boa Noite galera tudo bem? podem me ajudar? a entender porque as fotos não estão aparecendo no site?
[image: css das divs] aqui segue css delas.

aqui segue a foto do html com as divs

[image: Html com as divs]

e aqui segue foto do modelo do site de facul que estou criando para treino. a ideia é por as fotos no mesmo formato da biomedicina rente ao nome do curso colado na borda preta.

o site não envia passa de 2mbs. mesmo assim se puderem me ajudar comecei a mexer faz 14 dias e estou gostando muito e aprendendo todo dia.

Comment: abre a ferramenta de desenvolvedor do navegador e olha se não tem erros

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tenta baixar as imagens e usá-las localmente dentro do projeto ou... na div que está envolvendo essas divs de disciplinas coloca um: style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center;"

Answer (score -1):

Você deixou `height:25%;` se mudar para `px` `em` ou `rem` vai aparecer. Pode tambem setar um `min-height`:

```
   #bio{
    background-image: url("https://vaidebolsa.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/biomedicina.jpg.webp");
    width:238px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:25rem;
   }
```

Tente utilizar desse jeito que vai aparecer.